# Scrolling tween graphic

Tags: html5-canvas

Beginning in HTML5, I wrote, with a lot of patience, the code below on Animate HTML5 canvas in order to create an infinite graphic "recording an earthquake" style. The plot must be made from a point that indicates the ordinate of the points of the graph and this one must move to the left. After a lot of research, I can't create the scrolling. Many thanks to all those who can help me.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
var point = { x:800, y:50 };
 
createjs.Tween.get(point)
.to({x:800, y: 100}, 2000)
.wait(200)
.to({x:800, y: 150}, 2000)
.wait(200)
.to ({x:800, y: 200}, 2000)
 
function draw ()
{
    ctx.lineTo(point.x ,point.y );
    ctx.stroke();
}
 
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000'; 
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
 
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick1.bind(this));
function tick1()
{
    draw();
};
 
tick1();
ctx.moveTo(point.x,point.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I used CreateJs and used the class constructor var shape = new createjs.Shape(); which allows to draw and access to the drawing properties. Exactly like "CreateEmptyMovieClip" did.